# Excel-vba: Pasting Image only from Clipboard + allowing for re-use later

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to do allow the user to do following in excel. This would probably be achieved using macros.

1. User takes a screenshot, like with Snipping Tool
2. Code checks if the clipboard contains an image or not (code only to run only when clipboard holds an image)
3. Code will then paste the image from clipboard onto a specified area (e.g. Cell J55).
4. At the same time, I want to give this pasted image an ID (say, imgSource1), so that the user can later re-use this image on another sheet (say, on sheet 2, call for imgSource1 and paste it in there)

I've gotten thus far: learnt how to paste something into excel at the said location. I haven't been able to find a working code for checking if the clipboard is holding an image or not. Now I need to figure out how to paste only image (how to check clipboard is holding only image before pasting). The following code doesn't seem to work for me.

```
Sub btn_addImg1()
If (Clipboard.GetImage() != null)
    Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Range("J55"), Link:=False
Else
    'do nothing
End If
```

The "`If (Clipboard.GetImage()"` line is red, and it's telling me it needs a ")" at "`!=`".

Note that saving an image on a local drive is not a feasible solution for my situation. It **has** to be pasted from the clipboard.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out some workaround, but it need testing.

Btw, you need to go Tools -> References -> Microsoft Forms 2.0 Oject Librarty to make `MSForms` working.

```
    Sub btn_addImg1()
    Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    On Error GoTo Img
        GetClipboardText = DataObj.GetText
    On Error GoTo 0
Img:
    If Err = -2147221404 Then
        Err = 0
        Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Sheet1.Range("J55"), Link:=False
    Else
        'do nothing
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a try and report back how it goes. Just to be sure I understand the code:  we're using `MSForms` to check for the error. It first grabs the data from the clipboard and then sends it to the msform, and then checks for error. If an error is detected, it goes to `Img`. This is where I'm a little lost: what does `GetText` do?  Also,  why is `error =-2157221404?`

Comment: You use `GetText` to get a String from the `DataObj`, which contains a mirror of your clipboard. While your clipboard contains image, not String, `GetText` function returns error. This error number is -2147221404. You have to check if the same error pops out when clipboard is empty, or contains another type of object. That is why I said that it is some workaround, but it need testing. Looking forward for your feedback, and Happy New Year! :)