# Excel loading image from url

Tags: excel, image

I have this picture from a website that I am trying to insert into an excel spreadsheet.
I need to modify part of the url with data from a cell (this case cell B2). This specific picture is working fine if I don't modify it, but if I do modify it, it doesn't work.

Here's what I have so far...

```
Sub Chart()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

 Range("j3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("CHART1")).Select
    Selection.Delete
    
    
   
 _
        Dim Pict As Object

'// Note Inserts Picture Object @ Activecell and names it
Set Pict = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("https://stockcharts.com/c-sc/sc?s=" & Range("b2") & "&p=D&b=5&g=0&i=0&r=1598561613350")
Pict.Name = "CHART1"
Range("d10").Select


End Sub
```

Does it have to do anything with the format of the picture itself ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just change the workbook and worksheet references and this should work for you. I've cleaned up the recorded macro and gave your ranges references to the workbook and worksheet that the data is on. Using `ActiveSheet` can be unpredictable.

Note that the value in `B2` has to be a valid reference to the picture for it to work correctly.

Note that because those are not actual images (.jpg, .gif, etc) and are system generated, it took a little more work to get to work. This will make a copy of the site and paste it as an image.

```
Sub Chart()
    ' declare variable types - immutable                                    do not modify
    Dim WB As Workbook                                                      ' workbook reference    - full name of the .xlsm file
    Dim WS As Worksheet                                                     ' worksheet reference   - worksheet within workbook containing object
    Dim Pict As Object
    Dim imgLoc As String
    Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject

    ' variables - mutable                                                   ok to modify
    Set WB = Workbooks("SO.xlsm")                                           ' set the name of the origin workbook here
    Set WS = WB.Worksheets("63624135")                                      ' set the name of the origin worksheet here
    
    imgURL = WS.Range("B2")                                                 ' URL of image
    imgLoc = "A1"                                                           ' cell location of the image
    
    ' with thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/43522345/4101210
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate imgURL
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    End With

    IE.ExecWB 17, 0 '// SelectAll
    IE.ExecWB 12, 2 '// Copy selection

    IE.Quit
    
    ' with thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41394617/4101210
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    On Error GoTo Img
        GetClipboardText = DataObj.GetText
    On Error GoTo 0
Img:
    If Err = -2147221404 Then
        Err = 0
        WS.Paste Destination:=WS.Range(imgLoc), Link:=False
    Else
        'do nothing
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do get an error "unable to get the insert property of the picture class"

Comment: PICTURE IMPORT for workbook and PIC for sheet. Could you explain to me how you came up with that URL ? Trying to learn something.

Comment: I just realized something...if i change the value in cell B2 (different stock), with the link you provided, will it update the chart to the new stock ?

Comment: You are so helpful, but unfortunately it is still not working. I tried on a different machine with same outcome. Do I need an account with that bigstockphoto ? Could you still explain how you generated that link, please ?

Comment: Glad I can help :) how about this. What image are you looking to insert?

Comment: https://stockcharts.com/c-sc/sc?s=SPY&p=D&b=5&g=0&i=t3812754207c&r=1598713398729

Comment: other one is too long to paste in here

Comment: https://api.wsj.net/api/kaavio/charts/big.chart?nosettings=1&symb=tgt&uf=0&type=2&size=2&sid=166617&style=320&freq=1&entitlementtoken=0c33378313484ba9b46b8e24ded87dd6&time=8&rand=621124139&compidx=&ma=0&maval=9&lf=1&lf2=0&lf3=0&height=335&width=579&mocktick=1

Comment: just these 2. Stockcharts and Bigcharts. I didn't customize the second one to keep it short.

Comment: Hangs at Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject   . But just to be clear. What goes in B2 ? The ticker or the built up URL ?

Comment: Either one of the URLs you specified :) full url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220683/discussion-between-mech-and-serhito).

Comment: I wish I could say yes. Still stops at the Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject

Comment: Works for me. Join me in chat to get this figured out